# wordpress - how many characters can I have in a greek permalink?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

How many characters can I have in a **greek permalink** in my **WordPress** site?

I believe **russian** & **arabic permalinks** must have the same problem.

The reason I am asking is when I have a long permalink like this...

http://www.pharmamed.gr/c/γυναίκα/περιποίηση-προσώπου/ενυδάτωση-προσώπου/

I get a white page.

Comment: You should read [this topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53042/is-there-a-maximum-slug-length).

Comment: Although the topic you pointed was very useful, I found out that my problem was **"414 Request-URI Too Long"**! Any suggestions on this ??!

Comment: My guess is, that a plugin is returning the 414-header - can you give us a list of plugins you use? You could also just search your plugin files to see if one contains the number 414.

Comment: @vstm Thanks for the hint! It was **Better WP Security** plugin. So if anyone experience the same issue... Security->Tweaks->Other Tweaks - Prevent long URL strings (must be unchecked)